# Passing a string, to a javascript script, inside a slim template, in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In my controller, I have:

```
def view_chart
  @legend = "First Data Set"
  @labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
  @data_set = [100, 300, 200, 500, 250, 175, 500, 100, 300, 200, 500, 250]
end
```

And in my view, I have:

```
javascript:
  var lineData = {
    labels: #{raw @labels.to_json},
    datasets: [{
      label: #{raw @legend},
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      data: #{raw @data_set.to_json}
    }
```

This does not work, as I do not see the chart, when the view is rendered. If, however, I change the line:

```
label: #{raw @legend},
```

to:

```
label: "First Data Set",
```

The view (and chart) render properly. How do I pass a text string, to a javascript script, inside a .slim template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the output from erb:

```
javascript:
  var lineData = {
    labels: #{raw @labels.to_json},
    datasets: [{
      label: '#{raw @legend}',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      data: #{raw @data_set.to_json}
    }
```

You could also just construct the entire hash in ruby and convert it into JSON:

```
var lineData = <%=
   {
     labels: @labels,
     datasets: [{
       label: @labels,
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,0.2)',
       borderColor: 'rgba(114,102,186,1)',
       pointBorderColor: '#fff',
       data: @data_set
     }]
   }.to_json
%>
```